# In Visual Studio Code, the React Native suggestions do not show

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I am new to React Native. When I am typing in Visual Studio Code, it does not show any suggestions. I had tried to reinstall the all React Native extension, but it does not make any change. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the answer by removing Visual Studio Code and *after* uninstalling Visual Studio Code, removed the folders:

1. `%UserProfile%\.vscode`
2. `%AppData%\Code`
3. `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`

And after that, re-installed and everything is Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Change the language preference in vscode, botton right, and install necessary extensions from vscode extension menu

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions come from the Visual Studio IntelliCode. Go to extensions and install that extension or update if it needs updating. Also install Javacsript tools and if all fails try updating Visual Studio Code, then restart.

Answer (score 0):

Just *uninstall* Visual Studio Code and then remove the registry by,

1. click <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. type %AppData% and delete all the folders in the code.
3. reinstall Visual Studio Code. It's working fine for me.